# Oracle missing right parenthesis using TABLE(...) and object types

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get the reference of a tuple inside a nested table, but I'm getting an error,

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
SELECT REF(VALUE(a))
FROM CITY c, TABLE(c.airports) a
WHERE a.code = 'LHR';
```

The types I defined:

```
CREATE TYPE AirportType AS OBJECT(
    Code varchar2(10),
    Size int
);

CREATE TYPE AirportListType AS TABLE OF AirportType;

CREATE TYPE CityType AS OBJECT(
    Name varchar2(30),
    Airports AirportListType
);
```

This is how I create the City table:

```
CREATE TABLE CITY OF CityType
    NESTED TABLE Airports STORE AS Airport_Tab;
```

An example of an insert:

```
INSERT INTO CITY VALUES(CityType('London', AirportListType(AirportType('LHR', 999))));
```

Comment: Edit your question and add `create table city `  that you used as well.Also the records (sample) that you inserted.

Comment: @KaushikNayak Done.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to see in your output?

Comment: @ChrisSaxon just the reference, that's not my real query, but I need to get the reference to use it in a more complex query.

Comment: Why do you need a ref? What's wrong with the values themselves?

Comment: @ChrisSaxon I want the reference because I want more than one flight to store a reference to that airport. Storing the value is not logical in my opinion because I would need to create the same airport more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reference a single airport in your model. To reference an object you need an object identifier. Nested tables cannot have an OID. See restrictions regarding `oid_clause` in [nested_table_col_properties](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6).

Here's an example of a model which allows to references single airports.

#### The Model

```
CREATE TYPE AirportType AS OBJECT(
   code     VARCHAR2(10),
   the_size INTEGER
);
/

CREATE TYPE AirportListType AS TABLE OF REF AirportType;
/

CREATE TYPE CityType AS OBJECT(
   name     VARCHAR2(30),
   airports AirportListType
);
/

CREATE TABLE airports of AirportType (code PRIMARY KEY);


CREATE TABLE city OF CityType
    NESTED TABLE airports STORE AS city_airports;
```

#### The Data

```
INSERT INTO airports VALUES(AirportType('LHR', 999));
INSERT INTO airports VALUES(AirportType('LCY', 888));
INSERT INTO airports VALUES(AirportType('ZHR', 777));
INSERT INTO city VALUES(
   CityType(
      'London', 
      AirportListType(
         (select ref(a) from airports a where code = 'LHR'),
         (select ref(a) from airports a where code = 'LCY')
      )
   )
);
COMMIT;
```

#### The Query

```
SELECT a.column_value AS airport_ref
  FROM city c, table(c.airports) a
 WHERE deref(a.column_value).code = 'LHR';
```

#### The Result

```
AIRPORT_REF                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2202086CEE381BDAB100DFE053020011AC9C4C6CEE381BDAAF00DFE053020011AC9C4C
```